# Upper part of a view with rounded corners while on top of an ImageView Android-Java

Tags: java, android, view, imageview, overlay

[image]

All I want to know is how to achieve the highlighted part in the image whereas the upper part of a view has rounded corners while on top of another View where that view acts as the background, I've tried following Material Design's guidelines as to how use shapes or looking around the internet for something similar, yet came up with nothing.

**XML FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:theme="@style/gymTheme"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:src="@drawable/aagym"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            />

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:title="@string/search_hint"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/specific" />


</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_favorite_border_24"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/main.appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    />



<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"

    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    app:menu="@menu/gym_details_menu"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
    />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**This is how my Layout looks like**
[image]

Comment: You can use cardview for that and can modify that cardview using shape in the drawable folder

Comment: @youcantseeme I tried, it doesn't overlay the image, meaning the area that's been cropped its background is set to the White color instead of having the image view underneath it

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using fragment inside nested scrolled view? You can replace it with a custom view or include a view.
To achieve this you need to put a shape drawable with rounded corners, then add it as background in the first parent view of the nested fragment of yours. Finally, add some margin-top to the nested scroll view so you can hide the empty spaces from the rounded corners. Keep in mind that your parent's view must not have a background color just the child under the shape.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="40dp"
        android:topRightRadius="40dp" />
</shape>
```